# How to saved encrypted/hashing password in XML file using Java

Tags: java, xml, encryption, passwords

I want to save the password in XML file. But the plaintext is not secure enough. So I want to save it in hashed value or encrypted data. But I don't know how to do this. Since MD5 or SHA-2 is one way hashing. Or if I use salt, it should save the value of salt.

So what can I do? Please help me with this problem.

Comment: If you save a password, however it is encrypted, then it is vulnerable to attackers also decrypting it.

The reason for using a salted hash, is that given the real password and hashing it in the same way, you can compare the password without it leaving the client machine.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts Thank you for your reply. I just know the salt is a random string and it will hash with the password. It is more protection to password. But I don't know more detail about the salted password, could you explain more detail how the salted password works? Thank you

Comment: Hello, @patjing, it's really the hah that gets salted, not the password.

If you don't salt the hash, then any one can reproduce it by using a different password with the same hash - see Rainbow attacks.


The maths involved in hashing is complex, so I'm using a simplification.

Salting modifies the original data,to stop this. e.g., If the Hash for "Hello" is 1234 then we add a salt to the password we get a different hash. So let's suppose we add a * at the start, this will radically change the hash, but more importantly will prevent rainbow attacks.
e.g. has of "*Hello" might be 45454

Answer (score 1):

You can use `javax.crypto` package to encrypt/decrypt password.

First of all you have to define encryption secret and encryption init vector. For instance:

```
String secret = "Foo12345Bar12345";
String initVector = "randomInitVector";
```

Then you can write methods to encrypt/decrypt password.

```
public static String encrypt(String value, String secret, String initVector) {
    try {
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes());
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes(), "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, iv);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());
        return Base64.encodeBase64String(encrypted);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

public static String decrypt(String value, String secret, String initVector) {
    try {
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes());
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes(), "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, iv);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(str));
        return new String(decrypted);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

To run this code you need to add apache dependency to your project

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.9</version>
</dependency>
```

In addition, Java 8 has already tools to decode/encode Base64:
`java.util.Base64.getDecoder()` and `java.util.Base64.getEncoder()` so you can replace Apache with Java 8 impl